# Select records with repeatable datetime PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, datetime, intervals

I am facing this problem with a calendar.

I have to extract all records (events) (via select) with:
1. a specific date, or
2. repeatable date

The problem is that a normal calendar displays the entire month (or specific range of time), so it is possible to select a record from a subset generated from a subquery (and compare the date fragments), i.e.:

```
select (generate_series('2012-06-29 00:00:00',
                        '2012-07-03 00:00:00', 
                        '5 minutes'::interval))::timestamp;
```

I have to build the view of a calendar like an infinite list of events, that you can scroll down. So I have to display events one-by-one. When I select the events (i.e. 2012-06-29 00:00:00 to 2012-10-29 00:00:00), then the statement will not consider the record with date 2012-10-30 00:00:00, which is not expected.

How can I select multiple, non-continuous dates?

**The database schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."events" (
"id" int4 DEFAULT nextval('events_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
"date" timestamp(6),
"date_repeat_interval" interval(6),
"date_repeat_start" timestamp(6),
"date_repeat_stop" timestamp(6),
"event_name" varchar(255) NOT NULL
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
```

Insert some regular events on a specific date:

```
INSERT INTO "public"."events" VALUES ('1', '2013-04-18 14:04:39', null, null, null, 'Regular 1');
INSERT INTO "public"."events" VALUES ('2', '2013-04-19 14:04:50', null, null, null, 'Regular 2');
```

And insert some events with interval 1 and 2 days and specified repetition from and to date:

```
INSERT INTO "public"."events" VALUES ('3', null, '1 day', '2013-04-16 14:05:26', '2013-04-19 14:05:31', 'Repeatable 1');
INSERT INTO "public"."events" VALUES ('4', null, '2 days', '2013-04-17 14:05:49', '2013-06-15 14:05:53', 'Repeatable 2');
```

**Question:**

How to query database about all events in range: from NOW to infinity with LIMIT 10. that they occurs in order of occurence including multiple occurence for repeatable events.

Comment: In it's current form your question doesn't make sense. Why would you expect a timestamp outside the range you specify to be considered? Can you show table definitions and your sql query? You might want to make an sqlfiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com

Comment: What is a repeatable date?

Comment: Sure, I will reveal the topic. When We have repeatable events in your calendar and we want to present this not in range: day, week, month, year (where the time is in a specific range), but we want to present them as a scrollable list (to infinity), 10 items per page, there is the problem, how to query a database to display these events. You cannot close the range from now to X, because there may be an event on date X+1 minute. I have updated the question and included database schema with briefly explained problem.

Comment: As I'm not really sure why you would not expect the date 2012-10-30 to be skipped (as it is outside the range you provided), I'll suggest another way of thinking about the problem. I suggest not thinking about it as an SQL problem. Ask yourself: Can I generate the list (or boundaries) of the date range at all? If so, it's a simple matter of JOINs and maybe some UNIONs. If not, you do not have an SQL problem, but a problem to formulate the requirement. And, of course, there's always the possibility of SELECTing everything and weeding out on the application level.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a recursive CTE.  Note you really need to add limits to it or it will happily repeat to infinity.

```
WITH RECURSIVE event_calendar AS (
    SELECT id, coalesce("date", date_repeat_start) as e_date, event_name, 0 AS level
      FROM events
     UNION
    SELECT e.id, ec.e_date + date_repeat_interval, ec.event_name, ec.level + 1
      FROM events e
      JOIN event_calendar ec ON e.id = ec.id
     WHERE ec.level <= 10 and e.date_repeat_start is not null 
           and e.date_repeat_stop >= ec.e_date + date_repeat_interval
)
SELECT * FROM event_calendar order by e_date;
```